# What do Australians mean when they say 'He came a gutsa'?

Tags: slang, australian-english

What does it mean to 'Come a gutsa'?  I think I may have the Australian spelling right.

Answer (score 8):

The term *gutser* (variously spelled *gutzer*, *gutsa*) is documented by Eric Partridge in *The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English: A-I*.

A *gutser* is Australian slang for a heavy fall, or figuratively any abject failure. *Partridge* attests it at least as long ago as 1918. He provides several literary examples:

> - That slacked the chain. Prindy took a flying leap over the edge. He probably wouldn’t have heard Coon-Coon yell, ‘You treacherous little bastard!’ With both chains tautening, what began as a dive ended with a ***gutser***.
>     **—Xavier Herbert, *Poor Fellow My Country*, p. 978, 1975**
> - Anyhow, if the little tart what gave me the info about Annie’s place connects me with any reprisal against her bludger, then all our plans will have ***come a gutzer***!
>     **—Lance Peters, *The Dirty Half-Mile*, p. 289, 1979**
> - If you’re planning to spring any sort of ***gutzer*** here tonight, your missus’ll be the first to get it!
>     **—[*ibid.*, p. 151]**
> - Patrick said that if they ***come a gutsa***, the money is there to render assistance, and if no one is injured the money jackpots.
>     **—Roy Slaven (John Doyle), *Five South Coast Seasons*, p. 68, 1992**
> - He thinks the horse is doped. But after the race we’ll see what a good judge he is. Christ I hope he ***comes a gutser***.
>     **—Clive Galea, *Slipper*, p. 212, 1988**
>
> [*emphasis added*]

Perhaps the older term *come a **cropper*** influenced the coining of the one in question. *Come a cropper* is an older UK term that made the leap to Australia at least by 1927 according to *Partridge*. It has nearly same meaning: to fall or fail badly. The word *cropper* apparently derives from the equestrian term *crupper*, the horse’s hindquarters, and *come a cropper* originally meant to fall off the back of the horse.

It is also worth noting that *gutser* is also attested as New Zealand slang for a heavy eater (also from *Partridge*), i.e., someone with a big *gut*. It’s natural to wonder whether the NZ slang is related. After all, we refer to a person’s heavy fall or abject failure using the figurative language *falling on his face* (or *ass*). Falling on one’s *gut* is equally evocative, and *gutser* may have developed in an analogous way to *face-plant*.

Comment: I am delighted with the responses, and always thought it must have originated in the English 'come a cropper' Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may have slightly different meanings for other people (Australia’s a continent after all, plenty of space for variation), but for me, it’s got two meanings.  One is “to fall over/off and hurt yourself” (if *gutsa* has anything to do with *guts*, then this might be the more literal interpretation).

> The cyclist had come a gutsa in the rain and the bike had skidded into the traffic.

The other refers to things like plans or schemes and means ”go wrong, go awry” or better yet “come a cropper”.

> The council’s plans to stop accidents came a gutsa as soon as it started raining.

Here’s a real live example.  *Mel comes a gutsa with grog-free promise* is the headline for a [story](http://www.ntnews.com.au/article/2012/02/29/291251_entertainment.html) in which Mel (a radio host) has to backtrack on a public rant against non-drinkers, when she herself undertakes to stop drinking.

Answer (score 0):

[Why not try looking in a search engine before asking here?]

The first answer from *Google.co.uk* is a link to:

**come-a-gutsa**
Verb. (Australian colloquialism) To be thrown off a moving object at high speed, arms and legs flailing, landing on a hard surface and sustaining multiple wounds and broken bones.
*Slow down on that bike, Stevo!! You're gonna come-a-gutsa!!*

from: [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=come-a-gutsa)

Comment: *Urban Dictionary* is often wrong because of its lax editorial policy. An answer which depends only on it as a source is at risk of being downvoted.

Comment: Well, downvote it then if you want to! But the answer is consistent with the other answer given. However, my point is largely that this is general reference.

Comment: If you rely on urban dictionary as a general reference, you're gonna have a bad time.